# huge problem with linux distributions

Tags: usb, graphics, xubuntu

I have a question, please help me out. So, I can't install Debian based distributions on the pc. I've tried to install Elementary OS Isis, Ubuntu 14.04, Linux mint 17, xubuntu 14.04, Kubuntu 14.04 nothing works. First of all I can't even open installation window. When I plug in a bootable usb and try to boot it, the screen flashes and.. doesn't do anything. The only way to open installation wizard is to press TAB > F6 and edit boot line by adding command "nomodeset", but after installation goes reboot... after that the OS does not start correctly. I only see a bunch of colorful lines. Windows 8 installs without any errors.

PC is quite old. E4400 core duo cpu, 1.5GB of ram, and GT430 video card by Gigabyte, motherboard MSI - MS-7258.

I have no clue what's happening here, I've spent all day trying different distros.

Sorry for fast typing.. I'm frustrated, I have no idea which distro might work.. pc is not mine, friend of mine asked for Linux, and it seems he will have to stay with windows.

Strange thing, installation on my both pcs was fluent (Linux mint 17)

Oh one more thing elementary OS worked for short period of time, it worked while I've installed updates, rebooted it worked.. installed NVidia drivers 331.38 rebooted and after reboot screen with colorful lines appeared.

Comment: `nomodeset` makes Linux use basic graphics drivers to ensure compatibility with older cards. If an Ubuntu based distro cannot display on your computer without `nomodeset`, you may be out of luck. You might have to use a lighter OS, such as CrunchBang or Arch.

Comment: Does your motherboard have a VGA outlet? If yes, you can try to install without the graphics card - the typical intel chipset graphics is well supported with core duos.

Comment: unfortunately my motherboard doesn't have VGA, I'm stuck with GT430 only, but strange thing is that I have my own pc with GT440 and it works like a charm with every distro I choose, they have so close specs.. and way older cards works better, might be a bug! thanks for your time and help, I will try other distro that you mentioned!

Comment: UPDATE I managed to install latest release of Zorin OS installed nvidia drivers 319.32 works perfectly fine!! all compiz effects work, everything is fina finally, thank you for help!

Answer (score 1):

Don't tell me that, you have nvidia, old nvidia card having such issues with linux distros, i faced it too.

you have to install nvidia card driver by tty, reference http://www.howopensource.com/2012/10/install-nvidia-geforce-driver-in-ubuntu-12-10-12-04-using-ppa/

Tip : If you have kde based linux os ex: linux mint (KDE), **Go to system setting >> Desktop effects >> Advance , and click OPENGL 1.2**

I know you cannot see anything but if you shake your mouse on the screen you will get idea where is the options listed.

i am just sharing my experience, i know its irritating.